# MIMEs, octet-stream and Uploadify

Tags: file-upload, kohana, mime, uploadify, file-type

I'm using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) and [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) and I'm creating file uploader. User can upload only few types of files.

Kohana have great library of MIME types built-in. I thought that it would be cool to check that MIME type of uploaded file (it came from Uploadify) match setted file extensions. That's why I made an array of allowed MIME types.

```
$mimes         = (array) Kohana::config('mimes');
$allowed_mimes = array_merge($mimes['bmp'], $mimes['gif'], $mimes['jpg'], $mimes['jpeg'], $mimes['png']);
```

Next, I wanted to check that uploaded files MIME type is in `$allowed_mimes` array. I used something like `in_array($file['type'], $allowed_mimes)`. For surprise to me - actual MIME of file was `application/octet-stream`. Anyway, uploaded file was `JPEG` image. How this is possible?

Basic idea is that I need to check file type. What's the best way to do it?

**Edit:**

After some conversions with my colleagues, I decided to check chars after last dot. Like `virus.jpeg` is acceptable, because of `jpeg` is in its name. i'm still open for better solutions!

`$extension = ltrim(strrchr($file['name'], '.'), '.')`

Comment: `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` would be the proper way to get the extension (I can't understand the original question?)

Comment: Questions are: How to check file type? Is MIME okay way to do it? What the hell is `application/octet-stream` and how I got it for `JPEG`? Is my solution (see edit) okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can use [fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.setup.php) and [MIME Magic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mime-magic.installation.php) (has been removed from PHP 5.3.0) to determine files' MIME type (and so does Kohanas' `File::mime()` method).

In case that none of these 2 is available, this method will try to find the MIME type using files' extension, which can be highly unreliable.

Since you are only trying to validate some upload, I'd suggest using `Upload` methods to validate it:

```
$validation = Validation::factory($_FILES)
    ->rule('Filedata', 'Upload::not_empty')
    ->rule('Filedata', 'Upload::valid')
    ->rule('Filedata', 'Upload::size',  array(':value', '4M'))
    ->rule('Filedata', 'Upload::type',  array(':value', array('bmp','jpg','jpeg','png')))
    ->rule('Filedata', 'Upload::image', array(':value', 1920, 1080));
```

Notice that `Upload::image()` is available since 3.2.0 (you can import it into older versions as well). This is the validation I'm personally using for some Uploadify upload, so it should work just fine.