# How to restrict file upload using PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to do a restricted file upload using PHP.

I have used

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/dbase")
||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/dbf")
||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-dbase")
||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-dbf")
||($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "zz-application/zz-winassoc-dbf"))
```

For me .dbf (i.e Microsoft Visual FoxPro Table type) files are not working. Please suggest to me what I should put for the content type for .dbf .

Comment: Here are similar, unanswered question by me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845866/mimes-octet-stream-and-uploadify

Comment: have you tried `print_r($_FILES["file"]["type"]);` ?

Answer (score 2):

The browser uploading the file probably doesn't know it's an application/dbf mime-time, and sends it as the generic "application/octet-stream". The client/browser has to set the mime-type to be known on upload, and this can be altered by the user!

Thus MIME-type isn't reliable. If you want to be sure that it's the correct file-type/format, you'll have to examine the uploaded file.

Answer (score 2):

There is another easy way for this problem , instead of inspecting the MIME type,
we can get the file extension of the uploaded file by using this function.

```
$filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];   
 $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $ext = strtolower($ext);

 if($ext=="png"||$ext=="gif"||$ext=="jpg"||$ext=="jpeg"||$ext=="pdf"
        ||$ext=="doc"||$ext=="docx"||$ext=="xls"
        ||$ext=="xlsx"||$ext=="xlsm"||$ext=="dbf")
    {
        // your code whatever you want to write;

     }
```

Find an easy blob-upload and download of file here [Blob-upload](https://github.com/iamSampath/blob-upload)

Answer (score 1):

Defining the content type is up to the browser (or other client application), making it easy to tamper with  and **cannot be relied upon**. My guess is that your browser doesn't recognize the .dbf file and defaults to "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 1):

You can't depend on the type field of a file upload to actually determine its type.  First, it can be spoofed by the client.  Secondly, the client simply might not know what the file type actually is and just report 'application/octet-stream' instead.

you'll have to determine what kind of file was uploaded yourself.  Fortunately, PHP provides the fileinfo extension, which can help you with determining the type of a file.

Code example based on one from php.net:

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
echo finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) . "\n";
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Answer (score -2):

Try inspecting the MIME type being passed to you when you upload a file of that type. Insert a temporary `print $_FILES["file"]["type"];` somewhere in your code, then upload the file to  run the code and see what it prints out! You can then copy that type and use it in your if-statement.

Comment: And what if the type is "application-octet-stream" which is what it will default to if the browser doesn't recognise the actual file type?  And what if the type field is deliberately spoofed?

Comment: Then I would submit that he use the file type as just one of a number of checks to validate the upload.

Comment: I understand it's not reliable, but I feel can still be used. The user uploads and image file? It gets caught out by the type check. If the user uploads an image, but spoofs it as application-octet-stream, then other checks will catch it out.

Comment: And what if the user uploads a piece of malware and spoofs its filetype as something the system considers safe?

Comment: As I mentioned before, the type check is not the _only_ check in place. It would be part of any number of checks. Above, my example of an image was just that: an example. Shall we just agree that you find the MIME type to be completely unreliable and unusable, while I find there can be _some_ use for it.

Comment: As the type field is completely unreliable it should never be used.  It will only serve to throw you off and give you a false sense of security.  Magic quotes suffered from a similar flaw, which is why it is now considered bad practice to use it.